# Cakephp enum list with pre-selected drop-down box

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have this enum select list pre-selected with values then this is put into Form helper and select function like below:

```
$enumList = enum('Uusi hakija', 'Jatkohakemus', '40+', '60+','Työyhteisöhanke','Mieshanke','Urheiluseurahanke');
        $vars = explode('.', $enumList);
        echo $this->Form->select('Model.project_type', $vars);
```

My question is how can you set it so you define "selected" value with session value like below?

```
$saved = $this->Session->read('form'); 
echo $this->Form->input('amount_accepted',array('value' => $saved['amount_accepted'] ));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do it in the controller and pass it along to the view

```
if (!empty($this->data)) {
 ...
} else {
 # now comes your part
 $this->data['Model']['amount_accepted'] = $this->Session->read('Model.amount_accepted');
}
```

PS: why so complicated with the options?

```
$this->Form->input('amount_accepted', array('options'=>array('Uusi hakija', 'Jatkohakemus', '40+', '60+','Työyhteisöhanke','Mieshanke','Urheiluseurahanke')));
```

Comment: It's only a key value array, usually its a variable set from the controller which makes it look cleaner